# Who REALLY Leads the Guardians of the Galaxy?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy

After two solo films and major roles in Avengers: Infinity War and Avengers: Endgame, and an upcoming third feature, the group has gone through its share of battles together, but figuring out who’s in charge can be confusing at times, especially with the potential addition of Thor at the end of Endgame and a possible power struggle between him and Star-Lord. So who is actually leading the team?

Comment: I think the point in showing a difference in leadership (or lack there off on occasion) is to point out that it depends on the circumstances, supporting a theme that anyone can become a leader and/or that it's never about the leader, so much as the team.

Comment: I mean, it's obviously the rabbit. But given that Guardians 2 had two people literally competing to fly the ship ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## There is no set "leader"

Peter Quill is the nominal "Captain" (and thus "in charge" in his mind) because it's his ship they are riding in but these people are together by choice and decisions, at least from what we have seen, are made as a group.

They all have their input and if one of the group disagrees they are free not to take part.